# How to auto-generate docs for classes annotated spring jmx annotations

Tags: java, spring, javadoc, jmx

I have some code that uses these spring annotations:

```
org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedAttribute;
org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedOperation;
org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedOperationParameter;
org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedOperationParameters;
org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;
```

I want to generate some documentation (even just javadocs) using the comments in the annotations, for example consider the following method?

```
 @ManagedOperation(description="Does foo to bar")
 @ManagedOperationParameters({
 @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "bar", description = "The bar you want to foo.")})    
 public long fooBar( Bar bar) throws Exception {
   ...
 }
```

Is there some way I can automatically generate docs for this, or will I have to duplicate all the annotation strings in javadoc in addition to it?

Answer (score 2):

First, create a custom AnnotationMbeanExporter with a public method that delegates to getRegisteredObjectNames().   Use this as your mbeanExporter.

For example:

```
@Component
// This is a copy of the AnnotationMBeanExporter with a public version of getRegisteredObjectNames()
public class AnnotationMBeanExporter extends MBeanExporter {

  @Autowired
  MBeanServer mbeanServer;

  AnnotationJmxAttributeSource annotationSource = new AnnotationJmxAttributeSource();

  AnnotationMBeanExporter() {
      setServer(mbeanServer);
      setNamingStrategy(new MetadataNamingStrategy(annotationSource));
      setAssembler(new MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler(annotationSource));
      setAutodetectMode(MBeanExporter.AUTODETECT_ALL);
  }

  public ObjectName[] getExportedObjectNames() {
    return getRegisteredObjectNames();
  }
}
```

Then for your report, iterate over the object names returned from getExportedObjectNames() and get the relevant metadata for each JMX bean.

For example:

```
    for (ObjectName objectName: mbeanExporter.getExportedObjectNames()) {
      MBeanInfo mbeanInfo = mbeanServer.getMBeanInfo(objectName);
      MBeanOperationInfo[] operations = mbeanInfo.getOperations();
      // etc.
    }
```

Comment: I think you missed the 'java' tag

Comment: :) it's trivial to convert that to java.   i cut and pasted existing code.

Comment: I commiserate. My JMX annotations always make my JavaDoc tags [mostly] redundant. I wish JavaDoc would be flexibly promoted to first-class annotations. Sounds like a custom Doclet....